# How Can I implement OAuth2 SSO in a Java Application with Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, oauth, single-sign-on

I have searched but don't find any good example. I don't have any idea about it. Also, I don't want to use spring in my application

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Why Oauth2?  Is it a web based application or server-to-server?  Many or only a single authentication provider (i.e. do you want to have "login with google" and "login with microsoft", etc or just your own)?  We need significantly more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some libaries available , you may have a look at the non-Spring ones referenced at https://oauth.net/code/java/